# Sitio web con token dinámico de autenticación jmeter

Tags: aplicación-web, webtoken

Estoy iniciando con **jmeter**, estoy interesado en realizar pruebas de performance, principalmente de carga a un sitio web con autenticación.

Intenté grabar todo el proceso de autenticación, para posteriormente agregar peticiones HTTP (HTTP Request) a diferentes páginas de la aplicación web.

Al momento de correr las pruebas, **jmeter** genera un error en la petición POST de autenticación, esto es por que el token que previamente había guardado, ya no es el mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe algún elemento en jmeter que me permita obtener el token dinámico y lograr autenticarme?

Comment: Bienvenido ..., te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, espero mis modificaciones se ajusten más a las políticas del sitio.

Comment: Es importante leer los documentos. De hecho si realizas el [tour] obtendrás una medalla...

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer tres cosas.
1.- Alargar la vida del token
2.- Hacer la peticion del Login desde Jmeter
3.- Poner el Script de generacion del Token

En mi caso yo tambien estrece un Login, sin embargo mi data era encriptada, lo que hice fue poner el script o la porcion de codigo para generar el token.

Ademas ya que tienes grabado tu servicio, verifica que es lo que te sirve y que no

Comment: Tu token lo puedes generar en **PreProcessor** y despus extraerlo en un **PostProcessor** con **vars.put("token",vars.get("tkn_service"));**, **_token_** lo creas en variables definidas por el usuario